# Discrete Integration if List of Values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Lets say I have a list of values:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to generate a new list which is a simple integration of the original list:

```
b = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

I have come up with a few ways to do this, but I don't like any of them.  My first method uses a for loop:

```
b = [a[0]]
for index in xrange(1, len(a)):
    b.append(b[index-1]+a[index])
```

But this feel like too many lines.  My second method uses list comprehension:

```
b = [sum(a[:x]) for x in xrange(1,len(a)+1)]
```

Its fewer lines but it doesn't re-use the previous summation.  Is there an efficient way to do this operation with list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an efficient way to do this operation with list comprehension?

No -- Certainly not without ending up with an unreadable mess of code.  I would recommend you keep with the explicit for loop, but it could probably be cleaned up a little:

```
>>> b = [a[0]]
>>> for item in a[1:]:
...     b.append(b[-1] + item)
... 
>>> b
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

Note that python3.2 introduced [`itertools.accumulate`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) which does exactly what you want in an iterable though ...

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(it.accumulate(a))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a list comprehension but this could be called "an unreadable mess of code."

```
b = [b[idx-1] + val if idx-1 >= 0 else val for idx,val in enumerate(a)]
```

**EDIT**: So as I stated in my comment. I had already define b correctly from a previous test and so this code "worked". It doesn't. This isn't really great coding, but since I can't delete my answer...

```
b = []
junk = [b.append(b[i-1] + val if i - 1 >= 0 else val) for i,val in enumerate(a)]
```

This creates junk, which is an array of `None`, and b comes out correct. The cool thing is that this allows for very crude 'recursive' list comprehension.

Comment: I don't think that will actually work.  `b` doesn't exist when `b[idx-1]` is first referenced.

Comment: I just realized that myself. I thought it would work as it would and it work in my test...but I had b defined...